# Calling function outside file

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

im trying to call this function outside JSfile on main js but the console its throwing

Uncaught ReferenceError: Boxlayout is not defined main.js?fc8b2171b5ceebf37d7deb392265939f71c1a998:6(anonymous function)

this is my boxlayout.js

**boxlayout.js**

```
Boxlayout = (function () {
    var $el = $('#bl-main'),
        $sections = $el.children('section'),
        // works section
        $sectionWork = $('#bl-work-section'),
        // work items
        $workItems = $('#bl-work-items > li'),
        // work panels
        $workPanelsContainer = $('#bl-panel-work-items'),
        $workPanels = $workPanelsContainer.children('div'),
        totalWorkPanels = $workPanels.length,
        // navigating the work panels
        $nextWorkItem = $workPanelsContainer.find('nav > span.bl-next-work'),
        // if currently navigating the work items
        isAnimating = false,
        // close work panel trigger
        $closeWorkItem = $workPanelsContainer.find('nav > span.bl-icon-close'),
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
                'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
                'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        // transition end event name
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('transition')],
        // support css transitions
        supportTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;

    function init() {
        initEvents();
    }

    function initEvents() {

        $sections.each(function () {

            var $section = $(this);

            // expand the clicked section and scale down the others
            $section.on('click', function () {

                if (!$section.data('open')) {
                    $section.data('open', true).addClass('bl-expand bl-expand-top');
                    $el.addClass('bl-expand-item');
                }

            }).find('span.bl-icon-close').on('click', function () {

                // close the expanded section and scale up the others
                $section.data('open', false).removeClass('bl-expand').on(transEndEventName, function (event) {
                    if (!$(event.target).is('section')) return false;
                    $(this).off(transEndEventName).removeClass('bl-expand-top');
                });

                if (!supportTransitions) {
                    $section.removeClass('bl-expand-top');
                }

                $el.removeClass('bl-expand-item');

                return false;

            });

        });

        // clicking on a work item: the current section scales down and the respective work panel slides up
        $workItems.on('click', function (event) {

            // scale down main section
            $sectionWork.addClass('bl-scale-down');

            // show panel for this work item
            $workPanelsContainer.addClass('bl-panel-items-show');

            var $panel = $workPanelsContainer.find("[data-panel='" + $(this).data('panel') + "']");
            currentWorkPanel = $panel.index();
            $panel.addClass('bl-show-work');

            return false;

        });

        // navigating the work items: current work panel scales down and the next work panel slides up
        $nextWorkItem.on('click', function (event) {

            if (isAnimating) {
                return false;
            }
            isAnimating = true;

            var $currentPanel = $workPanels.eq(currentWorkPanel);
            currentWorkPanel = currentWorkPanel < totalWorkPanels - 1 ? currentWorkPanel + 1 : 0;
            var $nextPanel = $workPanels.eq(currentWorkPanel);

            $currentPanel.removeClass('bl-show-work').addClass('bl-hide-current-work').on(transEndEventName, function (event) {
                if (!$(event.target).is('div')) return false;
                $(this).off(transEndEventName).removeClass('bl-hide-current-work');
                isAnimating = false;
            });

            if (!supportTransitions) {
                $currentPanel.removeClass('bl-hide-current-work');
                isAnimating = false;
            }

            $nextPanel.addClass('bl-show-work');

            return false;

        });

        // clicking the work panels close button: the current work panel slides down and the section scales up again
        $closeWorkItem.on('click', function (event) {

            // scale up main section
            $sectionWork.removeClass('bl-scale-down');
            $workPanelsContainer.removeClass('bl-panel-items-show');
            $workPanels.eq(currentWorkPanel).removeClass('bl-show-work');

            return false;

        });

    }

    return {
        init: init
    };

})();
```

and im trying to init that function with

**main.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Boxlayout.init();

});
```

this code works outside meteor on other applications also i use the `$.(function(){});` from JQuery, but now im working on Meteor this just don't work, i read some documentation and stack overflow questions so i find this and try

[Older stack overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680710/should-i-use-meteor-startup-or-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your function is wrapped in parenthesis and called immediately with `()`, you are actually assigning `Boxlayout` to be the result of an anonymous IIFE (Immediate Invoked Function Expression), but that function does not currently return anything, so `Boxlayout` is set to `undefined` (and not the function itself). You first need to `return this` from the IIFE.

e.g. literally add this code at the end of the function:

```
return this;
```

You can structure it as a class instance and sets its `init` property to a function, within the "constructor" (removed all the rest of your code for clarity):

```
Boxlayout = (function () {

    // Set an init property of this instance to be a function 
    this.init = function () {
        alert("init")
    }

    // return the instance of this anonymous class
    return this;
})();

// Then to use it later
$(function () {
    // Call the init method on the specific single instance we created
    Boxlayout.init();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hzz9jqjc/1/

Comment: @Etjana: The example is just raw JS (except for the test line). Are you saying that the working JSFiddle does not work for you, or that you have not been able to apply it to your code? "That's not working" is not really enough information to go on :)

Comment: bro the answer was really nice, and its works sorry about that "not working", you know this is exactly want i wanna do, its the same example this is the package,https://atmospherejs.com/jelena/meteor-page-transitionsm seems like someone already have the same issue, but know its seems like the package don't working