# Meteor - Use JQuery

Tags: meteor

This is a noob question. I would like to use a few jQuery packages, as an example [jQuery.countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) . I'm aware that there is an atmosphere package for this however it is not up to date so it would be great to download the current version directly from the website and add it myself. If I do this where should I add these files in the meteor app and do I need to add the `<script>` reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery plugins in Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612383/using-jquery-plugins-in-meteor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggested place is to put them under client/compatibility. From the docs:

> client/compatibility
>
> This folder is for compatibility JavaScript libraries that rely on variables > declared with var at the top level being exported as globals. Files in this > directory are executed without being wrapped in a new variable scope. These > files are executed before other client-side JavaScript files.

However, if there are any CSS files or images associated with the package, then they will need to be put under public, and possibly under a subdirectory depending on how the urls are referenced by the package.

No script reference is required.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question.